# Best practice to deploy fixes in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

when I am in development I run the Play console locally with the command:

```
play ~run
```

When I change something in the code, the system recompiles the code immediately. So far so good.

I have deployed a couple of testing servers. What I've done is to install play on the servers and then copied the all project structure using GIT. Then I started the servers with the following command:

```
play start
```

And the last step is to hit CTRL-D to leave the console and keep the server running in the background.

Yesterday I needed to apply a couple of fixes. So I copied the code using GIT, but I couldn't find in any place instructions on how to stop the server and recompile. How can I do that? How would it be the best procedure to deploy a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should never compile your application on a production server. Depending on the size of your application, the power of your server, this can take a fairly long time. And a long compile time means a long deploy time which is in my point of view, bad.

What I suggest doing is :

1. Work locally with `play run`
2. Have a CI (or locally) compiling and packaging your application with `play dist`
3. Deploy your zip to production,
4. Unzip it
5. (bis) Stop currently running application with:

   ```
   kill `echo RUNNING_PID`
   ```
6. Start it with the `start.sh` script included.

EDIT : As Julien stated, you don't have to use the `kill -9`.

Comment: Actually I agree with you, I wrote this form my mobile as a direct answer 'how to stop the running app' and at office started to write about dist, when you posted your answer. BTW Personally I prefer to dist on the remote (non-production) machine and then copy to other machines in the same farm.

Comment: I just advise to kill without the "-9". Play apps responds perfectly to a gentle kill.